# A problem about two circles

Tags: circles

Inside one circle there is another, which is smaller, which touches the first one at one point. The radius of the first circle is twice the radius of the second. Distance between centers of the circles is 4. Find the radius of the smaller circle.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it not $4\,?$

Comment: Yeah, I think that the radius is 4 too. But the book says that the correct answer is 6. It's probably just a typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big circle radius = $R$
Small circle radius =$r$
$R = 2r$
Distance between centers $c = 4$
$4 + r = R$ (c + radius of small circle)
$4 + r = 2r$
$ r = 4$
$R = 8$

Comment: Yeah, I think that the radius is 4 too. But the book says that the correct answer is 6. It's probably just a typo...

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a figure makes everything obvious:

[image]

Comment: In the book where this problem is written, the picture appears to be drawn incorrectly. There the center of the larger one is inside the smaller circle, and not on its circumference. I didn’t even think about the fact that if the radius is twice as large, then the center of the larger circle must lie on the circumference of the smaller one...